# Mount 2 disks where one disk is the base and the disk contains the data changes from disk one

Tags: mount, virtualbox, virtualization

I want to build a test virtual Ubuntu machine.
But I don't want to copy all the files to the test machine disk.
But I can have the base disk be where the Ubuntu software is installed and the other disk is the disk that contains the data changes of the base disk. So you can easily recover and create a new test machine.

I would like to use VirtualBox on Ubuntu.

Is there an option to do that?

Maybe you can use mount on root directory (`/`) with two disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you're describing a basic overlay filesystem, like the live ISO's use. How about just:

- use a live ISO/USB with all changes in ram, and reboot to "reset" it
- Or use persistence to save changes over reboots, and erase the persistent files to "reset"

You could always use an overlay filesystem directly yourself, but the ISO's are already nicely set up & ready to roll. Here's some overlay info/help links:

- [Overlay Filesystem on kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt)
- [Overlay filesystem on wiki.archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem)

  > Overlayfs allows one, usually read-write, directory tree to be overlaid onto another, read-only directory tree. All modifications go to the upper, writable layer. This type of mechanism is most often used for live CDs but there's a wide variety of other uses.